# nginx windows 502 bad gateway on a laravel app inside a docker

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up Nginx and Laravel docker on my Windows development environment and I tried to access the app that is stored on docker and it returns 502 bad gateway.

I'm running my laravel app on Docker and trying to access it on my NGINX running outside a docker container which is the NGINX Windows

**my_app.conf**

```
upstream my_app {
    server localhost:9001;
}

server {
    server_name my_app.test;

    root "/app/public";

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~\.config$ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ /\.htaccess {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass my_app;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 7200;
    }

    location ~*\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|ico|xml|doc|xls|xlsx|woff|woff2|ttf|mp4|mov|avi|wav)$ {
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control no-store;
        root "/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/source code/my_app/public";
    }

}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  web:
    container_name: my_app
    image: 'bitnami/php-fpm:7.1'
    ports:
      - 9001:9000
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/Administrator/Documents/source code/my_app:/app
```

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host file**

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.1.2 host.docker.internal
192.168.1.2 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

127.0.0.1       my_app.test
::1             my_app.test
```